# Exceptions running HotswapAgent on tomcat spring project

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, hotswap, hotswapagent

Trying to set up HotSwapAgent for project (tomcat7-maven-plugin, spring 4.3.x, java 8)

basically according to example: 
- installed  `DCEVM`
- downloaded `hotswapagent.jar`
- run maven with vm options `-XXaltjvm=dcevm -javaagent:C:\developement\hotswap-agent-1.3.0.jar`

And when I run the project, it throws a lot of exceptions. (I'll attach stack trace in the end.). And looks like it wotks with pretty simple java changes, but no reaction when I for example change spring annotations.

```
    HOTSWAP AGENT: 14:52:21.369 ERROR (org.hotswap.agent.annotation.handler.PluginClassFileTransformer) - 
InvocationTargetException in transform method on plugin 'class org.hotswap.agent.plugin.tomcat.TomcatPlugin' class 'org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappLoader'.
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    ...
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:67)
Caused by: org.hotswap.agent.javassist.CannotCompileException: [source error] no such class: org.hotswap.agent.plugin.tomcat.TomcatPlugin
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.CtBehavior.insertAfter(CtBehavior.java:877)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.CtBehavior.insertAfter(CtBehavior.java:792)
    at org.hotswap.agent.plugin.tomcat.WebappLoaderTransformer.patchWebappLoader(WebappLoaderTransformer.java:63)
    ... 77 more
Caused by: compile error: no such class: org.hotswap.agent.plugin.tomcat.TomcatPlugin
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.searchImports(MemberResolver.java:470)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.lookupClass(MemberResolver.java:414)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.lookupClassByJvmName(MemberResolver.java:321)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atCallExpr(TypeChecker.java:683)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.JvstTypeChecker.atCallExpr(JvstTypeChecker.java:157)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.ast.CallExpr.accept(CallExpr.java:46)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.CodeGen.doTypeCheck(CodeGen.java:242)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:330)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:50)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.Javac.compileStmnt(Javac.java:567)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.CtBehavior.insertAfterAdvice(CtBehavior.java:892)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.CtBehavior.insertAfter(CtBehavior.java:851)
    ... 79 more

HOTSWAP AGENT: 14:52:21.468 ERROR (org.hotswap.agent.annotation.handler.PluginClassFileTransformer) - InvocationTargetException in transform method on plugin 'class org.hotswap.agent.plugin.tomcat.TomcatPlugin' class 'org/apache/naming/resources/ProxyDirContext'.
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    ...
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:67)
Caused by: org.hotswap.agent.javassist.CannotCompileException: [source error] no such class: org.hotswap.agent.plugin.tomcat.TomcatPlugin
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.CtBehavior.insertBefore(CtBehavior.java:774)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.CtBehavior.insertBefore(CtBehavior.java:734)
    at org.hotswap.agent.plugin.tomcat.WebappLoaderTransformer.patchProxyDirContext(WebappLoaderTransformer.java:163)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: compile error: no such class: org.hotswap.agent.plugin.tomcat.TomcatPlugin
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.searchImports(MemberResolver.java:470)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.lookupClass(MemberResolver.java:414)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.lookupClassByJvmName(MemberResolver.java:321)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atCallExpr(TypeChecker.java:683)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.JvstTypeChecker.atCallExpr(JvstTypeChecker.java:157)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.ast.CallExpr.accept(CallExpr.java:46)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.CodeGen.doTypeCheck(CodeGen.java:242)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atDeclarator(CodeGen.java:743)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.ast.Declarator.accept(Declarator.java:100)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:351)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:50)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.Javac.compileStmnt(Javac.java:567)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.CtBehavior.insertBefore(CtBehavior.java:754)
    ... 58 more

HOTSWAP AGENT: 14:52:22.345 ERROR (org.hotswap.agent.annotation.handler.PluginClassFileTransformer) - 
InvocationTargetException in transform method on plugin 'class org.hotswap.agent.plugin.logback.LogbackPlugin' class 'ch/qos/logback/core/joran/GenericConfigurator'.
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    ...
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:67)
Caused by: org.hotswap.agent.javassist.CannotCompileException: [source error] no such class: org.hotswap.agent.config.PluginManager
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.CtBehavior.insertAfter(CtBehavior.java:877)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.CtBehavior.insertAfter(CtBehavior.java:792)
    at org.hotswap.agent.plugin.logback.LogbackPlugin.registerConfigurator(LogbackPlugin.java:113)
    ... 95 more
Caused by: compile error: no such class: org.hotswap.agent.config.PluginManager
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.searchImports(MemberResolver.java:470)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.lookupClass(MemberResolver.java:414)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.lookupClassByJvmName(MemberResolver.java:321)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atCallExpr(TypeChecker.java:683)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.JvstTypeChecker.atCallExpr(JvstTypeChecker.java:157)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.ast.CallExpr.accept(CallExpr.java:46)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atCallExpr(TypeChecker.java:665)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.JvstTypeChecker.atCallExpr(JvstTypeChecker.java:157)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.ast.CallExpr.accept(CallExpr.java:46)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atCallExpr(TypeChecker.java:665)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.JvstTypeChecker.atCallExpr(JvstTypeChecker.java:157)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.ast.CallExpr.accept(CallExpr.java:46)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.CodeGen.doTypeCheck(CodeGen.java:242)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:330)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:50)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.Javac.compileStmnt(Javac.java:567)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.CtBehavior.insertAfterAdvice(CtBehavior.java:892)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.CtBehavior.insertAfter(CtBehavior.java:851)
    ... 97 more


Jul 20, 2018 2:52:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
737  [main] INFO  o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started 
829  [main] INFO  o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Jul 20 14:52:23 EEST 2018]; root of context hierarchy 
HOTSWAP AGENT: 14:52:23.125 ERROR (org.hotswap.agent.annotation.handler.PluginClassFileTransformer) - InvocationTargetException in transform method on plugin 'class org.hotswap.agent.plugin.spring.SpringPlugin' class 'org/springframework/beans/factory/support/DefaultListableBeanFactory'.
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    ...
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:67)
Caused by: org.hotswap.agent.javassist.CannotCompileException: [source error] no such class: org.hotswap.agent.config.PluginManager
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.CtConstructor.insertBeforeBody(CtConstructor.java:273)
    at org.hotswap.agent.plugin.spring.SpringPlugin.register(SpringPlugin.java:214)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: compile error: no such class: org.hotswap.agent.config.PluginManager
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.searchImports(MemberResolver.java:470)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.lookupClass(MemberResolver.java:414)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.lookupClassByJvmName(MemberResolver.java:321)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atCallExpr(TypeChecker.java:683)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.JvstTypeChecker.atCallExpr(JvstTypeChecker.java:157)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.ast.CallExpr.accept(CallExpr.java:46)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atCallExpr(TypeChecker.java:665)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.JvstTypeChecker.atCallExpr(JvstTypeChecker.java:157)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.ast.CallExpr.accept(CallExpr.java:46)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atCallExpr(TypeChecker.java:665)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.JvstTypeChecker.atCallExpr(JvstTypeChecker.java:157)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.ast.CallExpr.accept(CallExpr.java:46)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.CodeGen.doTypeCheck(CodeGen.java:242)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:330)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:50)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:351)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:50)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.Javac.compileStmnt(Javac.java:567)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.CtConstructor.insertBeforeBody(CtConstructor.java:261)
    ... 66 more

HOTSWAP AGENT: 14:52:23.146 ERROR (org.hotswap.agent.annotation.handler.PluginClassFileTransformer) - InvocationTargetException in transform method on plugin 'class org.hotswap.agent.plugin.spring.SpringPlugin' class 'org/springframework/beans/factory/support/DefaultListableBeanFactory'.
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    ...
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:67)
Caused by: org.hotswap.agent.javassist.CannotCompileException: [source error] no such class: org.hotswap.agent.plugin.spring.getbean.ProxyReplacer
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.CtBehavior.insertAfter(CtBehavior.java:877)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.CtBehavior.insertAfter(CtBehavior.java:792)
    at org.hotswap.agent.plugin.spring.getbean.ProxyReplacerTransformer.replaceBeanWithProxy(ProxyReplacerTransformer.java:43)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: compile error: no such class: org.hotswap.agent.plugin.spring.getbean.ProxyReplacer
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.searchImports(MemberResolver.java:470)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.lookupClass(MemberResolver.java:414)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.lookupClassByJvmName(MemberResolver.java:321)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atCallExpr(TypeChecker.java:683)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.JvstTypeChecker.atCallExpr(JvstTypeChecker.java:157)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.ast.CallExpr.accept(CallExpr.java:46)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.CodeGen.doTypeCheck(CodeGen.java:242)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.CodeGen.compileExpr(CodeGen.java:229)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atReturnStmnt2(CodeGen.java:615)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.JvstCodeGen.atReturnStmnt(JvstCodeGen.java:424)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:363)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:50)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:351)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:50)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atIfStmnt(CodeGen.java:398)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:355)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:50)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.Javac.compileStmnt(Javac.java:567)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.CtBehavior.insertAfterAdvice(CtBehavior.java:899)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.CtBehavior.insertAfter(CtBehavior.java:851)
    ... 67 more

HOTSWAP AGENT: 14:52:23.193 ERROR (org.hotswap.agent.annotation.handler.PluginClassFileTransformer) - InvocationTargetException in transform method on plugin 'class org.hotswap.agent.plugin.spring.SpringPlugin' class 'org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/XmlBeanDefinitionReader'.
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    ...
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:67)
Caused by: org.hotswap.agent.javassist.CannotCompileException: [source error] no such class: org.hotswap.agent.plugin.spring.scanner.XmlBeanDefinationScannerAgent
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.CtBehavior.insertAfter(CtBehavior.java:877)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.CtBehavior.insertAfter(CtBehavior.java:792)
    at org.hotswap.agent.plugin.spring.scanner.XmlBeanDefinitionScannerTransformer.transform(XmlBeanDefinitionScannerTransformer.java:28)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: compile error: no such class: org.hotswap.agent.plugin.spring.scanner.XmlBeanDefinationScannerAgent
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.searchImports(MemberResolver.java:470)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.lookupClass(MemberResolver.java:414)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.lookupClassByJvmName(MemberResolver.java:321)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atCallExpr(TypeChecker.java:683)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.JvstTypeChecker.atCallExpr(JvstTypeChecker.java:157)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.ast.CallExpr.accept(CallExpr.java:46)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.CodeGen.doTypeCheck(CodeGen.java:242)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:330)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:50)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.Javac.compileStmnt(Javac.java:567)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.CtBehavior.insertAfterAdvice(CtBehavior.java:899)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.CtBehavior.insertAfter(CtBehavior.java:851)
    ... 67 more

HOTSWAP AGENT: 14:52:23.595 ERROR (org.hotswap.agent.annotation.handler.PluginClassFileTransformer) - InvocationTargetException in transform method on plugin 'class org.hotswap.agent.plugin.spring.SpringPlugin' class 'org/springframework/context/annotation/ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider'.
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    ...
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:67)
Caused by: org.hotswap.agent.javassist.CannotCompileException: [source error] no such class: org.hotswap.agent.plugin.spring.scanner.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScannerAgent
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.CtBehavior.insertAfter(CtBehavior.java:877)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.CtBehavior.insertAfter(CtBehavior.java:792)
    at org.hotswap.agent.plugin.spring.scanner.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScannerTransformer.transform(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScannerTransformer.java:29)
    ... 94 more
Caused by: compile error: no such class: org.hotswap.agent.plugin.spring.scanner.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScannerAgent
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.searchImports(MemberResolver.java:470)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.lookupClass(MemberResolver.java:414)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.lookupClassByJvmName(MemberResolver.java:321)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atCallExpr(TypeChecker.java:683)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.JvstTypeChecker.atCallExpr(JvstTypeChecker.java:157)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.ast.CallExpr.accept(CallExpr.java:46)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atCallExpr(TypeChecker.java:665)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.JvstTypeChecker.atCallExpr(JvstTypeChecker.java:157)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.ast.CallExpr.accept(CallExpr.java:46)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.CodeGen.doTypeCheck(CodeGen.java:242)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:330)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:50)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:351)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:50)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atIfStmnt(CodeGen.java:398)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:355)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:50)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.Javac.compileStmnt(Javac.java:567)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.CtBehavior.insertAfterAdvice(CtBehavior.java:899)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.CtBehavior.insertAfter(CtBehavior.java:851)
    ... 96 more

HOTSWAP AGENT: 14:52:27.317 ERROR (org.hotswap.agent.plugin.proxy.ProxyPlugin) - Error modifying class for cglib proxy creation parameter recording
org.hotswap.agent.javassist.CannotCompileException: [source error] no such class: org.hotswap.agent.plugin.proxy.hscglib.GeneratorParametersRecorder
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.CtBehavior.insertAfter(CtBehavior.java:877)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.CtBehavior.insertAfter(CtBehavior.java:792)
    ...
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:67)
Caused by: compile error: no such class: org.hotswap.agent.plugin.proxy.hscglib.GeneratorParametersRecorder
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.searchImports(MemberResolver.java:470)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.lookupClass(MemberResolver.java:414)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.lookupClassByJvmName(MemberResolver.java:321)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atCallExpr(TypeChecker.java:683)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.JvstTypeChecker.atCallExpr(JvstTypeChecker.java:157)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.ast.CallExpr.accept(CallExpr.java:46)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.CodeGen.doTypeCheck(CodeGen.java:242)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:330)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:50)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.compiler.Javac.compileStmnt(Javac.java:567)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.CtBehavior.insertAfterAdvice(CtBehavior.java:899)
    at org.hotswap.agent.javassist.CtBehavior.insertAfter(CtBehavior.java:851)
    ... 76 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I just take the hotswap agent 1.1.0 version, and it's working fine now.